# How to add multiple login page in spring security xml file

Tags: spring, authentication

I am trying to log into different page form two different login page.
I tried the below process

```
<security:form-login login-page="/signinOne" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/user.html" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"/>

<security:form-login login-page="/signinTwo" login-processing-url="/login" default-target-url="/admin.html" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"/>
```

But it's not woking.it is redirecting only user.html page from both signinOne.html and signinTwo.html page.How can I solve this issue

Comment: Why don't you use the same login form in your different pages?

Comment: Then how will I redirect to different page.I mean is it possible to add multiple "default-target-url" here @akuma8

Comment: With this solution, you have 2 choices, using "default-target-url" then the authenticated user will be redirected to your default url or not using a default url then the user will be redirected to the requested page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define multiple entry points in your security configuration, i-e define multiple `http` tag. Like this :

For admin:

```
<security:http pattern="/admin/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
   <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
   <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="your entry point bean" />
</security:http>
```

For user :

```
<security:http pattern="/user/general/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"
 entry-point-ref="your entry point bean">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
 //form-login configuration      
</security:http>
```

See here for more explanations :
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points